# Question related to charged concentric conducting shells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electrostatics, self-energy

There is a charged conducting spherical shell given a certain positive charge.Another larger spherical shell is given the same negative charge.The first shell is now placed inside the second shell so that both are concentric.

Now how to find the electrostatic  energy stored in the system?Do we need to  consider self energy too ?What should be the necessary equations to be applied?

And suppose they are connected by a wire?Will the entire energy be converted into heat? Why?

Comment: If you have two concentric conducting shells, you have a spherical capacitor. The typical method for finding the electrostatic energy stored in the configuration is to use a spherical gaussian surface in order to find the field (hint: no net charge inside of the inner sphere and no net charge in the system as a whole). The electrostatic energy is found using $W = \int \left| \mathbf{E} \right|^2 d\tau$, which will consider the self-energy.

Comment: @kordon what if the charges are not equal...even then we can consider it as a capacitor?

Comment: Yes. A capacitor refers to two conducting surfaces which are placed some distance away from one another---regardless of the charges on each plate. In fact, you can calculate the capacitance of any conducting surface... but typically the word capacitor is used to refer to two conducting surfaces in which energy is stored in-between the surfaces.